# How to display matched data in Angular 5

Tags: angular

Initially, I am displaying student details from this array in HTML along with a text box.

**component.ts**

```
students=[{id:1,name:"john"}, {id:2,name:"dublin"},
          {id:3,name:"bhaskar"},{id:4,name:"robert"}]
```

**component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let x of students;let i=index">
{{x.name}}
<input type="text" [name]="'name'+i" >
</div>
```

Now I am getting 2 student details from database in an array

```
studentDetails=[{name:"john",marks:50},{name:"robert",marks:100}]
```

Now what I need is student name is matched with students array of the name then the marks will display in the particular text field

I got this link but he took empty objects in the array.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yowaud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I feel this is not the correct way.
Anyone, please help.

Comment: please check answer with solution here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1gyo9?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need to match the student name with `studentDetails` array of objects and `return` the match student marks like below.

**Example**

**component.ts**

```
  getStudentMarks(studentName) : number {
    let marks = 0;
    this.studentDetails.forEach(details => {

      if (studentName == details.name) {
        marks = details.marks;
      } 
    })
    return marks;
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let x of students;let i=index">
    {{x.name}}
    <input type="text"  [value]="getStudentMarks(x.name)"  >
</div>
```

**[Here is solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1gyo9?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You can bind Marks field before hand and then when student details come from DB just update it like below

```
students=[{id:1,name:"john"},{id:2,name:"dublin"},{id:3,name:"bhaskar"},{id:4,name:"robert"}]
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let x of students;let i=index">
{{x.name}}
<input type="text" [name]="'name'+i" [(ngModel)]="x.marks">
</div>
```

once you get data from DB you just need to update original stident array and update marks in that

```
studentDetails=[{name:"john",marks:50},{name:"robert",marks:100}]

for(let student of studentDetails) {
 let matchedStudent= students.find(w=>w.name === student.name);
  if(matchedStudent)
   {
    matchedStudent.marks=student.marks;
   }
 }
```

Since here using two way data model .. your html will update once model get updated

**Note: But make sure name is unique field, generally it should be Id**

Answer (score 0):

**on component.html add following code:**

```
<div *ngFor="let x of students;let i=index">
  <div *ngFor="let j of studentDetails">
    <input *ngIf="x.name == j.name" type="text" [name]="'name'+i" 
       [value]="j.marks">
  </div>
</div>
```